# Generic array - Unchecked cast from Object[] to T[]

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting

I am very new to Java and I have have read some general information about typecasting, which is probably the solution to my problem.
And I think I do grasp the concept in general - like if there was just one method one would like to use which has been made for a different class. But I am unable to apply it to my own code with generic arrays because I don't know at which point to cast and which method or do I have to make a loop to send the entire array through?

Here is my mergesort algorithm which should probably be working fine if it wasn't for the generic type ...

```
package src;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

// sort array of type T using the Mergesort algorithm
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] sort(T[] arr) {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] leftArray = (T[]) new Comparable[12]; // ERROR: Type safety: Unchecked cast from 
 // Object[] to T[]
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T[] rightArray =(T[]) new Comparable[12]; // ERROR: Type safety: Unchecked cast from 
 // Object[] to T[]

    if (arr.length > 1) {


        int half = arr.length / 2;

        leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, half);
        rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, half + 1, arr.length);

    }
    return merge( sort(leftArray), sort(rightArray));
}

private static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] merge(T[] leftArray, T[] rightArray) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] tempArray = (T[]) new Comparable[12];   // ERROR: Type safety: Unchecked cast from 
 // Object[] to T[]
     int i = 0;
     int leftIndex = 0;
     int rightIndex = 0; 

    while ( leftIndex < leftArray.length ||  rightIndex < rightArray.length ) {
        if ( leftIndex < leftArray.length && rightIndex < rightArray.length ) {
            if (leftArray[leftIndex].compareTo(rightArray[rightIndex]) < 0 )  {
                 tempArray[i] = leftArray[leftIndex] ;
                 leftIndex++; 
            }
            else {
                 tempArray[i] = rightArray[rightIndex] ;
                 rightIndex++; 
            }
        }
        else if ( leftIndex < leftArray.length ) {
                tempArray[i] = leftArray[leftIndex] ;
                leftIndex++; 
        }       
        else if ( rightIndex < rightArray.length ) {
            tempArray[i] = rightArray[rightIndex] ;
            rightIndex++;   

        }           
    } // end while  

    return tempArray;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Edit this line to check with different values for the array
    // or add more unit tests to test/MergeSortTest.java

    // // sort list of Characters
    Character[] charArr = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r',
            'l', 'd', '!' };

    charArr = MergeSort.<Character> sort(charArr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArr));

    // sort list of Integers
    Integer[] intArr = { 23, 4, 15, 8, 42, 16 };

    intArr = MergeSort.<Integer> sort(intArr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr));
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't anything you can do about it. Because of type erasure, the type information that could be used to see if the cast would work is lost, and so the check has to be deferred to runtime, where a `ClassCastException` could be thrown, terminating your program. As the compiler cannot prove that this will not happen, it emits a warning instead.

---

One more thing -- your code is going to fail anyways. Types are erased to their bounding type, which in this case is `Comparable`. Thus, code like this:

```
T[] leftArray = (T[]) new Object[12];
```

Gets erased to this:

```
Comparable[] leftArray = (Comparable[]) new Object[12];
```

And because `Object` does not implement `Comparable`, the cast will fail.

The solution is to create `Comparable` arrays instead:

```
T[] leftArray = (T[]) new Comparable[12];
```

Comment: Or to use `ArrayList`s instead and have no casts whatsoever.

Comment: What's the difference? You can use `Arrays.sort()` and you don't even need lists. In my understanding, the OP is trying to implement a sorting algorithm as an exercise. I don't see how using a collection interferes with the task at hand.

Comment: @Tom Nothing really. You're probably right in that it's an exercise, and that functionally there wouldn't be a difference between manipulating arrays vs `ArrayLists`, unless it's part of the assignment, or if performance is a concern.

Comment: @user3580294 Thanks a lot for the quick help. At least the complier starts working now! The new problem is: it has problems with the line  `return merge( sort(leftArray), sort(rightArray));` which I find confusing because both methods `sort` and `merge` are extended to `Comparables` at src.MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java):23)` any idea why that might be, eclipse does not mark anything at that line but keeps complaining about an unchecked from Object[] to T[].

Comment: @Tom unfortunately we are not allowed to use lists.

Comment: thats the result so far ... I don't understand the compilers statement `[Ljava.lang.Comparable;@13060ee9
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
...
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
 at src.MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:21)`

Comment: @user3667784 Are you getting an error or warning? And can you update your question with your code so I can try it?

Comment: @user3667784 And that's a pretty strange stack trace... Did you add print statements to `sort()`?

Comment: I have edited the code. Which was just exchanging `object` with `comparable`an I had an orpahned `i` to delete.  In Eclipse I get a warning and at command line it says `exception` ...

Comment: @user3667784 Are you sure your new code is right? I copy-pasted your code, and I'm getting errors in lines 40, 44, 49, and 53 because it doesn't appear you declared `i`

Comment: sorry I had a temporary printout line which caused the strange stack trace... here is what happens without this print line: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
 at src.MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:19)
 at src.MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:22)` at line 19 `leftArray` is initialized,  at line 22 is: `return merge(sort( leftArray), sort (rightArray)) `

Comment: @user3667784 Can you post code that will compile first?

Comment: @user3580294 I am awfully sorry, It seems I deleted the wrong `i` I have replaced it again...

Comment: @user3667784 The problem is that when you try to call `merge()` and `sort()` returns two arrays of length 1, your `if` condition in `merge()` skips assigning shorter arrays to `leftArray` and `rightArray`, so you basically start all over with two arrays of size 12. This process repeats until you get a `StackOverflowError`. Also, the upper bound for `Arrays.copyOfRange()` is *exclusive*, so you don't need the `+ 1` offset.

Comment: @user3667784 If you use a debugger, the problem becomes quite clear

Comment: @user3580294 Thanks a lot for your help, your time and effort. I will have to rework my algorithm then and do some research on how to use a debugger :)